# request.getParameter returns null value: JSP, servlet

Tags: jsp

i have connected my login.jsp and registration.jsp to my database, signup is successful but when i login i get error message "password invalid"  i think my code has a problem, please can someone help me solve that, the code is found below . Thanks in advance.

login.jsp

```
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%
    String userid = request.getParameter("uname");
    String email = request.getParameter("emailsignup");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = 
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mldn","root","shaddy");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs;
    rs = st.executeQuery("select * from members WHERE uname='" + userid + "' and password='" + password +"'");
    if (rs.next()) {
        session.setAttribute("userid", userid);
        out.println("welcome " + userid);
        out.println("<a href='logout.jsp'>Log out</a>");
        response.sendRedirect("<a href='index.jsp'>Welcome</a>");
     } else {
        out.println("Invalid password <a href='index.jsp'>try again</a>");
    }
%>
```

**HTML**

```
<header>
                <h1>Geo Business/Land inventory<br><span>Login And Registration</span></h1>
            </header>
            <section>               
                <div id="container_demo" >
                    <a class="hiddenanchor" id="toregister"></a>
                    <a class="hiddenanchor" id="tologin"></a>
                    <div id="wrapper">
                        <div id="login" class="animate form">
                            <form  action = 'jsp/login.jsp'> 
                                <h1>Log in</h1> 
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="username" class="uname" data-icon="u" > Your Username </label>
                                    <input id="username" name="username"  required="required" type="text" placeholder="myusername." value=""/>
                                </p>
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="password" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p"> Your password </label>
                                    <input id="password" name="password"  required="required" type="password" placeholder=" X8df!90EO" value=""/> 
                                </p>
                                <p class="keeplogin"> 
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="loginkeeping" id="loginkeeping" value="loginkeeping" /> 
                                    <label for="loginkeeping">Keep me logged in</label>
                                </p>
                                <p class="login button"> 
                                    <input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
                                </p>
                                <p class="change_link">
                                    Not a member yet ?
                                    <a href="#toregister" class="to_register">Join us</a>
                                </p>
                            </form>
                        </div>

                        <div id="register" class="animate form">
                            <form  action = 'jsp/registration.jsp'> 
                                <h1> Sign up </h1> 
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="fname" class="fname" data-icon="fn">First Name</label>
                                    <input id="fname" name="fname" required="required" type="text" placeholder="myfirstname" value=""/>
                                </p>
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="lname" class="lname" data-icon="ln" >Last Name</label>
                                    <input id="lname" name="lname" required="required" type="text" placeholder="lastname" value=""/> 
                                </p>
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="email" class="emailsignup" data-icon="e" >Email</label>
                                    <input id="email" name="email" required="required" type="email" placeholder="cug@wuhan.cn" value=""/> 
                                </p
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="username" class="uname" data-icon="u">Username </label>
                                    <input id="username" name="username" required="required" type="username" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO" value=""/>
                                </p>
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="password" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Password </label>
                                    <input id="password" name="password" required="required" type="password" placeholder=" eg.X8df!90EO" value="" />
                                </p>
                                <p class="signin button"> 
                                    <input type="submit" value="Sign up"/>
                                </p>
                                <p class="change_link">  
                                    Already a member ?
                                    <a href="#tologin" class="to_register"> Go and log in </a>
                                </p>
                            </form>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>  
            </section>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: kindly use taglibs instead of scriptlets if possible, use `PreparedStatement` istead of `Statement`, also whats the column type of password in table? Here spaces might be an issue.

Comment: please post your html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that the Username and Password you requesting from your html form is correct.

The `request.getParameter` method returns the value of the input form field which have the same name given inside the parenthesis.

For example:

html:

```
<form action="/action.jsp">
<input type="text" value="text" name="input1">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

action.jsp:

```
String text=request.getParameter("input1");//will return the value 'text'
```

Please try printing the value in jsp and make sure the values are  intact

Comment: ,Thanks for your respond here is my HTML. its too log

Comment: its too long to upload but i will try to do that in parts ASAP. THNKS

Comment: <h1>Log in</h1> 
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="username" class="uname" data-icon="u" > Your email or username </label>
                                    <input id="username" name="username"  required="required" type="text" placeholder="myusername or mymail@mail.com" value=""/>

Comment: <p> 
                                    <label for="password" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p"> Your password </label>
                                    <input id="password" name="password"  required="required" type="password" placeholder=" X8df!90EO" value=""/> 
                                </p>

Comment: </p>
                                <p class="keeplogin"> 
         <input type="checkbox" name="loginkeeping" id="loginkeeping" value="loginkeeping" /> 
         <label for="loginkeeping">Keep me logged in</label>
        </p>
                                <p class="login button"> 
                                    <input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
        </p>
                                <p class="change_link">
         Not a member yet ?
         <a href="#toregister" class="to_register">Join us</a>
        </p>
                            </form>

Comment: REGISTRATION FORM: <form  action = 'jsp/registration.jsp'> 
                                <h1> Sign up </h1> 
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="usernamesignup" class="uname" data-icon="u">Your username</label>
                                    <input id="usernamesignup" name="usernamesignup" required="required" type="text" placeholder="mysuperusername690" value=""/>
                                </p>
                                <p>

Comment: <label for="emailsignup" class="youmail" data-icon="e" > Your email</label>
                                    <input id="emailsignup" name="emailsignup" required="required" type="email" placeholder="mysupermail@mail.com" value=""/> 
                                </p>
                                <p>  <label for="passwordsignup" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Your password </label>
                                    <input id="passwordsignup" name="passwordsignup" required="required" type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO" value=""/>
                                </p>

Comment: <p> 
                                    <label for="passwordsignup_confirm" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Please confirm your password </label>
                                    <input id="passwordsignup_confirm" name="passwordsignup_confirm" required="required" type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO" value="" />
                                </p>
                                <p class="signin button"> 
         <input type="submit" value="Sign up"/>
        </p><p class="change_link">

Comment: please update your question with this html including form element

Comment: hi Nishad ive updated the question.Thanks for your support i reviewed my form and realized username and passwords where not matching, as you mentioned in your first comment, ive corrected that and login is now ok.

Answer (score 0):

I was making the same mistake, in HTML part the input type tag should have a name attribute which can be the used by getParameter Method to get the input from the user.